# How to send a notification in web app when a json value changes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I did everything in this document https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=en , so I can to send a notification manually. But I want to send it if the value entered by the user is the same in the json.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code demonstrating the issue? Since you are new, I would suggest reviewing these documents: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no "issue" in the code,  I don't know how to send notifications automatically...

Comment: Ah. Perhaps this is the wrong forum then. This forum is for help with issues in existing code (see the links in my prior comment). If you need a tutorial, there are a number which will be revealed with a google search - [this one](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-tutorial-using-firebase/) looks interesting.

Comment: I know how to do it in android app but in a web app I got stuck